# Animation not working as expected(Went through code several times also had a look at other post but no solution.)

Tags: css, animation

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&family=Reggae+One&display=swap');
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(main.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 100;
}

html::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: -10;
}


/*Main text on the main page*/

.maintext {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  /* border: 2px solid red;  */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.maintext h1 {
  color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Reggae One', cursive;
  /* border: 2px solid red;  */
  margin-top: -10px;
  animation: show .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  color: black;
}

.maintext h1 span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  background-color: red;
  animation: overlay 1s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .5s;
}

h1:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

h1:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

h1:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

h1:nth-child(1) span {
  animation-delay: .5s;
}

h1:nth-child(2) span {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

h1:nth-child(3) span {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

.maintext .butt {
  position: relative;
  left: 900px;
  top: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: 'Reggae One', cursive;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  color: white;
}

.maintext .butt:hover {
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 200px 200px rgba(92, 137, 204, .3);
  background: transparent;
}

@keyframes overlay {
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  100% {
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="maintext">
    <h1>Hello, <span></span></h1><br>
    <h1>My Name is <span></span></h1><br>
    <h1>ABC XYZ <span></span></h1><br>

    <button class="butt">Portfolio</button>
  </div>

</section>
```

Output is: as in code but only scans one line at a time one after another.

I have been through the code several times, I did every h1 one by one, I cant see whats wrong.  I have had a look at other posts as well but could not find the solution, I am sure I have typed correctly but for some reason its playing up.

You guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/centaur26/tLqu57em/

Comment: Please could you describe what you expected compared to what you have. I can't see anything wrong with the output of the snippet because for all I know that is the result you wanted.

Comment: Hi @A Haworth: this is what I wanted: https://jsfiddle.net/centaur26/tLqu57em/9/  , Its working now thanks to @Prakash M.

Answer (score 2):

There you added `<br>` after every `h1`. So in css you can't get second `h1` by `:nth-child(2)`. You have need to change those by `:nth-child(1) :nth-child(3) :nth-child(5)`

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&family=Reggae+One&display=swap');
    
    html
    {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            background-image: url(main.jpg);   
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            background-size: cover;
            z-index: 100;
     }
    
     html::after{
             content:"";
             position: absolute;
             left:0;
             top:0;
             height: 100%;
             width:100%;
             background-color: black;
             opacity: .5;
             z-index: -10;
             
     }
    
    
     /*Main text on the main page*/
     .maintext
     {
             display:block;
             height:auto;
             /* border: 2px solid red;  */
             padding:0;
             margin:0;
            
    }
    
    
    .maintext h1{
            color:transparent;
            display:inline-block;
            position: relative;
           
            font-family: 'Reggae One', cursive;
            /* border: 2px solid red;  */
            margin-top: -10px;
            animation: show .5s ease forwards;
            animation-delay: 1s;
            color:black;
    }
    
    
    
    .maintext h1 span{
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 0;
            background-color: red;
            animation: overlay 1s ease forwards;
            animation-delay: .5s;
    }
    
    
    
    h1:nth-child(1){
            animation-delay:1s;
    }
    
    h1:nth-child(3){
            animation-delay:2s;
    }
    
    h1:nth-child(5){
            animation-delay:3s;
    }
    
    h1:nth-child(1) span{
            animation-delay:.5s;
    }
    
    h1:nth-child(3) span{
            animation-delay: 1.5s;
    }
    
    h1:nth-child(5) span{
            animation-delay: 2.5s;
    }
    
    
    
    .maintext .butt{
            position: relative;
            left: 900px;
            top: 200px;
            width: 250px;
            height: 50px; 
            padding :5px 30px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            background-color: transparent;
            font-size: 25px;
            font-weight: bolder;
            font-family: 'Reggae One', cursive;
            letter-spacing: 4px;
            transition-duration: 2s;
            transition-timing-function:ease;
            color:white;
            
    } 
    
    .maintext .butt:hover
    {
            color: black;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 200px 200px rgba(92,137,204,.3);
           background: transparent; 
    }
    
    @keyframes overlay {
            50%{
                    width: 100%;
                    left: 0;
            }
            100%{
                    left:100%;
                    width:0;
            }
    }
    
    @keyframes show{
            100%{
                    color:white;
            }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>My Portfolio</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="portfolio.css">
        </head>

        <body>
        
        <section class="hero">
               
                <!-- <div class="menu">
                        <ul>
                                <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Work Experience</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></samp></li>
                        </ul>
                </div> -->

             
                <div class="maintext">
                        <h1>Hello, <span></span></h1><br>
                        <h1>My Name is <span></span></h1><br>
                        <h1>ABC XYZ <span></span></h1><br>

                        <button class="butt">Portfolio</button>
                </div>

        </section>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a "tidy" button in the snippet that'll auto format your code...

Comment: OMG, that is exactly it, awesome spotting, I was not aware of br taking 2nd child and so on. Staring at code over and over couldnt figure out what it was. Thanks heap, highly appreciated.

Comment: why is <br> a child of h1??